# Some function are not available when i do require_once in php file

Tags: php

I have 2 function in a php file and that file in included in another php file, the issue is 1 function is available and other function is not available.

Available Function:

```
function get_visits_count($enterprise_id, $date1=NULL,$date2=NULL)
{
    global $DB;

    $_enterprise_id=filter_var($enterprise_id,FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

    if(isset($date1) && isset($date2))
    {
    $query="select COUNT(DISTINCT visit_id) AS count FROM user_activity where DATE(time_stamp) between '$date1' and '$date2' and enterprise_id=".$_enterprise_id;

    }
    else
    {
    $query="select COUNT(DISTINCT visit_id) AS count FROM user_activity where enterprise_id=".$_enterprise_id;
    }

    $stmt = $DB->query($query);

    if(!$stmt)
    {
        return -1;

    }
    else
    {

    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    //var_dump($row);
    return $row['count'];

    }
}
```

NOT AVAILABLE FUNCTION :

```
function get_bounce_counts($enterprise_id, $date1=NULL,$date2=NULL)
{
    global $DB;

    if(isset($date1) && isset($date2))
    {
    $stmt = $DB->prepare("select visit_id, from user_activity where enterprise_id=:id and DATE(time_stamp) between :date1 and :date2 group by visit_id having count(visit_id)=1");
    $stmt->bindValue(':id', $enterprise_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':date1', $date1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':date2', $date2, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    }
    else
    {

    $stmt = $DB->prepare("select visit_id, from user_activity where enterprise_id=:id group by visit_id having count(visit_id)=1");
    $stmt->bindValue(':id', $enterprise_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    }
    $stmt->execute();
    if(!$stmt)
    {
        return -1;

    }
    else
    {
    $row_count = $stmt->rowCount();

    if($row_count>0)
    {

    return $row_count;

    }
    else
    {
        return 0;

    }
    }
}
```

I am using phpstorm IDE also not showing any error and that not available function also not available in structure of php file.

Comment: can you post code, where you including these files, please?

Comment: public function getEnterpriseStats($eid, $date1 = null, $date2 = null)
    {
        $stats = array();

        $stats['visits_total']    = get_visits_count($eid, $date1, $date2);
        $stats['visits_average']  = get_average_visit_count($eid, $date1, $date2);
        $stats['bounce_count']    =  get_bounce_rate($eid,$date1,$date2);
        return $stats;
    }

Comment: get_visits_count() also in that file its available but get_bounce_rate is not available.

Comment: if there is issue in my code then phpstorm should show all functions in structure of file.

Comment: Try get_defined_functions() to check which all functions are available in the file.

Answer (score 0):

The "not available function" is declared as `get_bounce_counts()`. You're calling `get_bounce_rate()`. That's the problem.

```
public function getEnterpriseStats($eid, $date1 = null, $date2 = null) 
{ 
    $stats = array(); 
    $stats['visits_total'] = get_visits_count($eid, $date1, $date2);
    $stats['visits_average'] = get_average_visit_count($eid, $date1, $date2);
    $stats['bounce_count'] = get_bounce_rate($eid,$date1,$date2); 
    //                       ^---- is this function declared anywhere
    return $stats; 
}
```

Comment: i am just showing few functions its a large file, get_bounce_rate() is available in file. but when i call that function it says undefined function.

Comment: I mean to say exactly is that there are few function are available and some are not available but file contains all functions :(

Comment: What means "not available"? Do you get a fatal error along the lines of `Call to undefuned function` or?